# How to set multiple filters using useLazyQuery

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I want the page to fetch some data on load, and display it (this works), but also have some filters above. I can get the filters to *kind of work*...
But what is happening is when I select "All" from my Select, it will never reload. I checked the network tab, and it looks like it will run a query using the last previous value, but then also without any value there but never update the UI. How can I solve this?
Also, it looks like my data is loading twice on page load, I am guessing because of the way I have set up the `useEffect`, but I am not sure what to do here?

This is the important part of my code looks like -

```
export default function Home() {
  const [runewords, setRunewords] = useState<Runewords[]>([]);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
  const [sockets, setSockets] = useState("");

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_RUNEWORDS, {
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
  });

  const [searchRunewords] = useLazyQuery(SEARCH_RUNEWORDS);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRunewords(data?.runewords?.data);
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleSearch();
  }, [sockets, searchText]);

  const handleSearch = async () => {
    const results = await searchRunewords({
      variables: {
        search: searchText,
        ...(sockets && {
          sockets: +sockets,
        }),
      },
      fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
    });

    if (results) {
      setRunewords(results?.data?.runewords?.data);
    }
  };

  const handleSearchTextChange = async (e: any) => {
    setSearchText(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Input onChange={handleSearchTextChange} />
      <Box>
        <HStack>
          <Select
            onChange={(e) => {
              setSockets(e.target.value);
            }}
            placeholder="Sockets"
            width={"30%"}
            borderRadius={"8px"}
            backgroundColor={"white"}
          >
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
          </Select>
        </HStack>
      </Box>
      <SimpleGrid margin={"32px 32px 0px 32px"} columns={[3, 1, 2, 3]}>
        {!loading &&
          runewords &&
          runewords.map((runeword) => (
            <Runeword key={runeword.id} {...runeword.attributes} />
          ))}
      </SimpleGrid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```